# Regular expression is being too greedy

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a regular expression but it’s being too greedy. The input string could be in either of the following formats:

```
STUFF_12_1234 or STUFF_1234
```

What I want to do is to create a regular expression to grab the characters after the last `_`. So in the above examples that would be the numbers “1234”. The number of characters after this last `_` varies and they could be a combination of letters and numbers. I have tried the following expression:

```
_(.*?)\Z
```

This works for “STUFF_1234” by returning “1234” but when I use it against “STUFF_12_1234” it returns “12_1234”

Anyone advise on how the expression should be changed to fix this?

Comment: You can split the string by `_`, and pick the last item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to grab the text appearing after the last underscore `_`:

- Keep the current regex, but specify [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) `RegexOptions`. Since the regex is searched from right to left, the lazy quantifier will match as few character as possible up to just right after the last `_` in the string.
- Modify the regex to disallow underscore `_` in the text you want to match:

  ```
  _([^_]*)\Z
  ```
- Split the input string by `_` and pick the last item. For this [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.string.split.aspx) is sufficient, no need for [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx).

Comment: Some great answers but this one is the most comprehensive, giving three different options. I almost got the correct expression but decided to post on here and go to lunch. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the `_` from the list of valid chars:

```
_([^_]*)\Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regexp

```
_([^_]*)\Z
```

Regular expressions search left-to-right, so greediness controls whether they stop early or late. But it won't change the location of the left end of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1. With regex:

   ```
   _([^_]*?)
   ```

   You just need not to select the `_` character or

   ```
   _(\d*?)
   ```

   If you know the characters are numeric (`\d`)
2. With substring:

   ```
   yourString.Substring(yourString.LastIndexOf('_')+1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s_YourString="STUFF_12_34";
String s_OP = Regex.Match(s_YourString, "_[^_.]+$").Value.Trim('_');//Output:34            
s_YourString="STUFF_1234";
s_OP = Regex.Match(s_YourString, "_[^_.]+$").Value.Trim('_');   //Output:1234
```